# JFileChooser "Save As" compound document - overwrite existing

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm working on a system which uses compound documents to store its data.

Everything is working beautifully - I even have nice icons and double-click-to-open working on the open dialog.

My problem is with the "Save As" dialog.  If I save as a compound document that doesn't already exist then all is fine.  If I double-click an existing compound document, then my code asks if you want to overwrite it, and that is also fine.

What is working wrong, though, is if you type in the name of an existing compound document and click save, it acts as if you clicked cancel instead.

I'm using a FileFilter and a FileView to configure all the display and filtering of the files.

Here's my main dialog opening function:

```
public void saveAs() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter filter = new SketchFolderFilter();
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);

    javax.swing.filechooser.FileView view = new SketchFileView();
    fc.setFileView(view);

    fc.setCurrentDirectory(Base.getSketchbookFolder());

    int rv = fc.showSaveDialog(this);

    System.err.println("Option: " + rv);
    if (rv == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File newFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
        System.err.println("Save As: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (newFile.exists()) {
            int n = twoOptionBox(
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                "Overwrite File?",
                Translate.w("Do you really want to overwrite the file %1?", 40, "\n", newFile.getName()),
                "Yes", "No");
            if (n != 0) {
                return;
            }
            newFile.delete();
        }
        loadedSketch.saveAs(newFile);
    }
}
```

And here, if you need it, is my filter and view classes:

```
public class SketchFileView extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileView {
    public String getTypeDescription(File f) {
        if (Base.isSketchFolder(f)) {
            return Translate.t("UECIDE Sketch Folder");
        }
        return Translate.t("Directory");
    }

    public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
        if (Base.isSketchFolder(f)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 

    public Icon getIcon(File f) {
        if (Base.isSketchFolder(f)) {
            ImageIcon icon = Base.loadIconFromResource("icon16.png");
            return icon;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class SketchFolderFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if (Base.isSketchFolder(f)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Translate.t("Sketch Folders");
    }
}
```

When it works, I see, on stderr:

```
Option: 0
Save As: /foo/bar/baz
```

When it doesn't work I see:

```
Option: 1
```

## Clarification:

This is as far as I understand purely a problem with **compound documents**.

To reiterate the scenario:

1. Open a JFileChooser to save your data to a **compound document**.
2. You have a list of existing **compound documents**.
3. You double click one - the APPROVE_OPTION index is returned, and getSelectedFile() returns the File object, or
4. You type the name of a **non-existant compound document** and press "Save" or the return key.  The APPROVE_OPTION index is returned, and getSelectedFile() returns the File object, but
5. You type the name of an **existing compound document** and either press "Save" or the return key.  The CANCEL_OPTION index is returned, and getSelectedFile() returns null, or
6. You press the "Cancel" button. The CANCEL_OPTION index is returned, and getSelectedFile() returns null.
7. You then use the File object with your own code to generate the **compound document** - typically deleting the old one (if it's there and the user says he wants to overwrite) and making the directory and filling it with your files.

It's 5 that is (in my opinion anyway) wrong.  It should return APPROVE_OPTION and getSelectedFile() should return a File object representing the file you typed in resident in the directory the JFileChooser's in (i.e., the same as 3).

## Edit:

Narrowing it down.  It looks like JFileChooser doesn't like it when a folder is non-traversable and you enter its name into the chooser and hit return - it tries to traverse into it and it fails miserably, and doesn't know what to do with it, so just dumps you out of the JFileChooser returning 0.  Here's an SSCCE that demonstrates it.  Run this on a folder with a folder within it called "test.X" and type in "test.X".  It should fail.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class fctest {

    public class SketchFileView extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileView {
        public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".X")) {
                return false;
            }
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        } 
    }

    public class SketchFolderFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".X")) {
                return true;
            }
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "Sketch Folders";
        }
    }

    public void saveAs() {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter filter = new SketchFolderFilter();
        fc.setFileFilter(filter);

        javax.swing.filechooser.FileView view = new SketchFileView();
        fc.setFileView(view);

        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));

        int rv = fc.showSaveDialog(null);

        System.err.println("Option: " + rv);
        if (rv == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File newFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            System.err.println("Save As: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fctest main = new fctest();
        main.saveAs();
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked up the meaning of "compound document". It sounds to me like it is just a file that might be used by "Word" or "Excel" for example. `5.You type the name of an existing compound document and either press "Save" or the return key. The CANCEL_OPTION index is returned, and getSelectedFile() returns null, or` - When I type "abc.xlsx" and then press "Save" I get "abc.xlsx" displayed on the console. A file name is just a file name. The File API does not know what the content of the File represents. I use JDK7 on Windows 7. Maybe a file names means something different on another platform.

Comment: I notice you are using a custom filter and FileView. Could these be the problems?

Comment: In Java the concept of a "compound document" is simply a folder with other files in, where the entire folder represents the document to load.  See the page on "How to Use File Choosers" in the Swing help (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).  It mentions them in passing under the "Boolean isTraversable(File f)" heading.  The filter and view is what makes the compound document concept work.

Comment: I just stripped my code right down to try and make an SSCCE, but the stripped down version is working right.  It must be something to do with the filtering somehow.  Edit: yes, it's to do with the filtering system.  It breaks JFileChooser.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's the isTraversable() functionality.  Without that, if you type an existing dir name and hit return it changes into that directory.  If it's not traversable then it doesn't know what to do with it, so it fails miserably.  It wants to change into the directory but can't.  I'll post my SSCCE up top as well, so you can try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is if you type in the name of an existing compound document and click save, it acts as if you clicked cancel instead.

I think you mean the file chooser closes, but you would like it to remain open to give the user a chance to change the file name. If so, then you can override the `approveSelection()` method of the JFileChooser to display the confirm dialog:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class FileChooserSave
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( new File(".") )
        {
            public void approveSelection()
            {
                if (getSelectedFile().exists())
                {
                    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        this,
                        "Do You Want to Overwrite File?",
                        "Confirm Overwrite",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                        super.approveSelection();

                }
                else
                    super.approveSelection();
            }
        };

        chooser.setSelectedFile( new File("something.rob") );
        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
           System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile() );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit:

I added the following:

```
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

It allowed you to select a "compound directly" but you could also select a non compound directory which was some progress.

I then override the "approveSelection" method of the file chooser to only approve compound directories and it now seems to work reasonably well?

Must admit I don't know why it does what it does so its more of a brute force approach.

Here is the code I tested:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class fctest {

    public class SketchFileView extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileView
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
            if (f.getName().startsWith("images")) {
                return false;
            }
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false; // added this
        }
    }

    public class SketchFolderFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if (f.getName().startsWith("images")) {
                return true;
            }
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "Sketch Folders";
        }
    }

    public void saveAs() {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser()
        {
            public void approveSelection()
            {
                if (getSelectedFile().getName().startsWith("images"))
                    super.approveSelection();
            }
        };

        javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter filter = new SketchFolderFilter();
        fc.setFileFilter(filter);

        javax.swing.filechooser.FileView view = new SketchFileView();
        fc.setFileView(view);

//      fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        fc.setSelectedFile( new File("blog") );

        int rv = fc.showSaveDialog(null);

        System.err.println("Option: " + rv);
        if (rv == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File newFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            System.err.println("Save As: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fctest main = new fctest();
        main.saveAs();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I think you mean the file chooser closes, but you would like it to remain open to give the user a chance to change the file name." No, I want it to close, but close as if you'd pressed "save", and return the path /path/to/my/dir/enteredfilename as it does if the file doesn't exist or if you double-click on an existing file.

Comment: I just tried that code out of curiosity, and it works just the same.  It's like the JFileChooser is assuming (wrongly) that I will be saving a plain file, so entering a name that exists as a directory (compound document) it assumes must be wrong, so cancels.  Incidentally, all this used to work fine (though looked horrible) with a FileDialog instead of a JFileChooser.

Comment: `I just tried that code out of curiosity, and it works just the same.` Maybe you don't understand the functionality of a JFileChooser. The file choose doesn't actually "save" the file for you. You need to write code to save the file to disk. All the file chooser does it get the name of the file for you. The code I provide will return this file name when you click the "Save" button and then click "Yes" on the confirm dialog.

Comment: Yes yes yes, I understand all that. I have code to do the saving.  That is all fine. The problem is that "All the file chooser does it get the name of the file for you." is erroneous.  It gets the name for you if: 1. the "compound document" doesn't exist and you type the name, or 2: the "compound document" does exist and you double click it. If it does exist, but you type the name in, then the "save" button acts like the "cancel" button and getSelectedFile() is null and the return value is 1 not 0 (save is index 0, cancel is index 1). I imagine it's fine with simple files, but not compounds.

Comment: Bingo!  The setFileSelectionMode is what was missing!  That's now working exactly as I want.  Thanks!